# Changing time base after applying raised cosine filter

Tags: fft, filters

I am generating a random sequence binary 0 and 1 to have a signal.

```
Nbit = 20;                      
R = 20;                         % Bit rate
Tr = 1/R;                       % bit period (ns)
x  = randi([0,1],1,Nbit);       % Binary signal 
N = length(x);
t  = Tr:Tr:N*(Tr);       % Time base (ns)
```

Then, I found that to make the signal band-limited I should pass it through a raised cosine filter.

```
rolloff = 0.25;                                    % Rolloff factor
span = Nbit;                                       % Filter span in symbols
sps = 1e3;                                         % Samples per symbol
b = rcosdesign(rolloff, span, sps, 'normal');      % Rasied cosine filter
d = upfirdn(x, b, sps);                            % upsample and filter the input data
t_new = Tr/sps:Tr/sps:N*(Tr/sps);                  % New time base (ns)
```

I think upsampling by a factor of sps means that sampling time in  t_new should be Tr/sps. My question is how I should define time base after applying the raised cosine filter? And why is the begenning andend of the signal goes to zero? Am I using the filter correctly?
plot of d look likes below figure with x = [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0]

I do appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that span in the rcosdesign() fn call sets the length of the filter, in symbols. So your filter length will end up being $span*sps+1$, or in this case $20*1000+1=20001$ taps.

The new time axis that you've computed there is accurate for the delta (Tr/sps), but note that the endpoints there aren't accurate. This relates to why you're asking about the edges going to zero - if you think about sliding your input signal (after zero-insertion) across the filter (convolution), the beginning and end of that process have periods where there is not a full overlap and cause the smaller values there.

If you were doing the upsampling and convolution manually, e.g. inserting the zeros and then using the matlab conv fn, you could actually use the 'same' parameter on the conv function so that it only returns values the same size as the first input vector.

Alternatively, you could just truncate your existing data to do the same thing. Note that the group delay of a FIR filter N taps long is $(N-1)/2$ so you can cut off that amount of samples at the beginning and the end and get what you're looking for.

However, I personally wouldnt bother truncating it at all unless you have a good reason to.

Here is some example code of doing an untruncated version vs truncated version with the correct time axis (using the conv method - note I was lazy and re-used the upfirdn function to just do zero insertion, there are better ways..). Alternatively you could modify this to manually truncate the vector yourself as I described. Note that I started the time-axis at zero as its easier to write out.

```
d2 = conv(b,upfirdn(x,[1],sps),'same');

t_new = 0:Tr/sps:N*Tr;
figure(1)
plot(t_new,d2);
title('conv-same options')

figure(2)
d = upfirdn(x, b, sps);                          
t_new = 0:Tr/sps:Tr*(2*N-1);
plot(t_new,d);
title('untruncated option')
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and help!